# Multithreading not effective with StereoBM for small images

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, arm, real-time

I do stereo matching with OpenCV's StereoBM on an ARM Cortex-A7 (Raspberry Pi 2). I am limited to CPU processing so the only way to speed things up is to lower the resolution to QVGA or even QQVGA. I want to process as fast as possible. Since the images are quite small StereoBM tends to use only 1 or 2 threads instead of 4.

The default number of threads is being calculated like this in [stereobm.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/stereobm.cpp):

```
double N0 = 8000000 / (useShorts ? 1 : 4);  // approx tbb's min number instructions reasonable for one thread
double maxStripeSize = std::min(std::max(N0 / (width * ndisp), (wsz-1) * SAD_overhead_coeff), (double)height);
int nstripes = cvCeil(height / maxStripeSize);
```

Basically the image is divided into stripes which are then processed with parallel_for_. I dont know the idea behind maxStripeSize but it probably is trying to optimize the thread size based on various parameters (number of disparities etc.) and it probably works well for bigger images.

I am able to force a fixed number of threads by setting the nstripes variable. I measured following with StereoBM:

sub-QVGA (320x158):

- 1 thread = ~90ms
- 2 threads (OpenCV default) = ~50ms
- 4 threads forced = ~50ms

QQVGA (160x120):

- 1 thread (OpenCV default) = ~20ms
- 4 threads forced = ~20ms

One can clearly see that there is no speedup at QVGA and QQVGA at 4 threads. Why? I suspect the parallelization overhead may be too large for small data and thus not effective. From my tests bigger images tend to be more effective with multithreading.

I am limited to using CPU only in my current HW design. Is there a way how to more effectively use all 4 CPU cores or process the stereo faster in general? Would GPGPU (CUDA or OpenCL) tend to perform better with these small images? I want to employ real-time vision. One possible solution may be to rewrite StereoBM to FPGA but I want to avoid this.

Configuration note: Using OpenCV 3.0.0. I tested both TBB and PTHREADS and they seem to behave the same with threading. Also I have NEON and VFPV3 enabled in OpenCV (even though RPi2 seems to use VFPV4).

Comment: Previously posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48219/755

Comment: To summarize comments I left on the CS.SE copy: the best idea I could come up with was to do coarse-grained parallelization where frame #1 is given to CPUs 1&2; frame #2 is given to CPUs 3&4; frame #3 is given to CPUs 1&2; and so on.  For QVGA this should achieve approximately 40FPS throughput but 50ms latency per frame, so it doesn't quite achieve real-time processing.  It sounds like the OP would prefer a solution with less latency (closer to real-time processing).